# Rails: Best practice for many inter-field custom validators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, customvalidator

I am working on a Rails project that has some pretty complex validation requirements. This project outputs data for upload to a state reporting system, so I want to raise validation problems in my system before I try to upload it to the state. Here are some examples of the validations:

- Field A must be blank if Field B is set, or Field B must be blank if Field A is set.
- Field C must be 0 if Field D is 0, 6 or 9
- Field E must have a value if Field F is set.
- etc.

Is it best practice to use methods in the model for custom validation, one custom validator class for the model, or a custom validator class for each business rule?

Answer (score 0):

If you have reusable custom validation logic, you're probably best off putting them in a single CustomValidator module and mixing it into whatever classes need to use them.

So the answer is that the model is the correct place to state the validation rules; just use whatever helpers you can to make it DRY.